# Finding the equation of a line parallel to a tangent and passing through different points.

Tags: derivatives, curves

I started out with the equation $f(x)=1/x^2 + 3x -4$ going through points $(1,0)$ and found the equation of the line tangent to this (and written in gradient intercept form) as **y=1x+-1** (PS I'm not actually sure if this is right, I'm usually okay at differentiation but the $x^2$ as a denominator really threw me)
Now the next question is asking me to find the equation of a line parallel to this tangent, but going through points $(2,-3)$. I have no clue how to start this, doesn't a line parallel have the same slope? Do I just plug in the different X and Y values but keep my previously found slope of 1? Or should I start from scratch all over again?? Please help!

Comment: Your equation is $y = mx + b$, where you know the slope $m$.  Now find $b$ such that the line passes through the stated point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the tangent line is absolutely correct.

To get an idea of how lines transform on changing $m$ and $c$ in the equation $y=mx+c$, I would recommend playing with [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/straight_line_graph.html)

It will be clear after this demonstration that parallel lines have the same slope.

So, let the equation of your new line be $y=x+c$. To find $c$ , Satisfy the point $(2,-3)$ in the line. You have the answer! Cheers :)